# Integral involving the gamma function

Tags: integration, number-theory, gamma-function

If we define $$f(x) = 1 + \frac{\cos\big(\pi\frac{\Gamma(x) + 1}{x}\big)}{2 - \cos(2\pi{x})}$$ how would one go about evaluating
$$ \int_1^R \frac{1}{x} \log{f(xe^{i\alpha})} dx$$ for some parameter angle $\alpha$ and an arbitrarily large $R$ (needs to hold above any particular constant threshold)?  I know I'm supposed to show some progress but I really have no idea how to do this.

Comment: *how would one go about evaluating* - One wouldn't.

Comment: @Lucian Why not? Is it not possible to even try to evaluate it numerically?

Comment: what do you mean by arbitrarily large $R$? You want to take the limit as $R \to \infty$ or you want the result to hold for a general $R$ above a certain threshold $\theta$  (and you don't care how big $\theta$ is)?

Comment: @Ant The second one - sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: crosslisted at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/229065/integral-involving-the-gamma-function